# Does anyone know of a hello world website?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I'm learning a practice called 'web scraping' using python. From what I can tell so far the idea is to send out a request to load the site data from a server, store the DOM html in a variable, and then basically data mine the s*** out of the resulting string until you are able to quickly access exactly and only the information you need.

Well I'm ready to start fiddling with statements that might help me do the actual data mining, but first I need to see and understand all of the html in my string. After I've got the hang of it I won't care what the html looks like, but right now I need to be able to reference it to properly analyze my output. so far I've tried google, python.net, youtube, various blogs and etc. But they all look like alianeese.

I'm just looking for the typical stuff you know?

```
<html><head><meta><script src=""><style src=""><title></title></head><body><div class=""><img src=""></div><div><h1>my page</h1><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><p>click <a href="">here</a></p></div></body></html>
```

You get what I'm saying? Just a website... that uses like... html... to render some simple structured data.

*P.S.* This is kind of neat. I went to give this post some tags and I discovered 'simple-html-dom'. So I googled it. Apparently it's some kind of language that lets you parse html from online sources in exactly the way I am trying to. I may check that out later, but I still want to figure out how to do this with python.

**EDIT** Actually something like [this](https://www.hackthissite.org/) would work fine but it's just so big. I would prefer something smaller to work with.

Comment: Why dont you just run your own webserver? You can then create the pages as you wish. You should also look at beautiful soup (http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/beautifulsoup/)

Comment: +1 for beautiful soup. But stay aware that most todays sites are using javascript view rendering so you can't just use the result of your HTTP request. The fun is to dig deeper in order to find the AJAX call returning data (nicely formatted json or xml).

Comment: @richerlariviere I don't fully understand what you just said, but I'm glad you said it, because it feels like one of those things that will make sense after I've dived in a little bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it would probably be nice to build your own web pages to use, you can also try looking for pages "optimized for lynx". [Lynx](http://lynx.browser.org/) is a text-only browser with which "simple" pages naturally work best.

Most of the links you'll find will be dead already, but I found this list for instance, which still has many alive and equally simple pages: http://www.put.com/dead.html (please ignore the content itself... there is no particular reason I chose this example other than that it probably works nicely for your purposes!)